# React Native: Re-render component in time interval

Tags: android, react-native, httprequest

I have a component inside my `render()` function that returns a list of elements to de displayed on a view. This component (parent) refeers to a child component that has an `http` request to a API. This request is responsable for returning the list of elements with its data. Basically the data returned from the database is the other users of the app and its positions. Everything works just fine.

The thing is that I wanna be able to re-render the component when data change in the database, thus, one user will know the position of the others whenever it changes.

I tought about using a method with `setInterval` to keep making requests to de database and update (re-render) the component inside the `render()` function when some change in the db is detected, but I'm having some problems. Here's what I have:

```
render(){

    return(

        <View>
            <Component_to_re_render/>
        </View>

    );

}
```

I wonder if there's way to do something like...

```
render(){

    return(

        <View>
            {this.re_render_component()}
        </View>

    );

}

re_render_component(){
    "This function would make the component be re-rendered  with the new 
     data received from the API in a period of time."
}
```

Can someone help me to make this work? It does not need to be done in the exact way that I'm proposing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you save your response in a component state and render the state in the component it will automatically re-render when a data change has occurred. No need to have an interval (except if you need to to the request in an interval).

Something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

    state = {text: ''}

    componentDidMount(){
        someKindOfHttpRequest().then(response => this.setState({text: response}))
    }

    render() {
      return <Text>{this.state.text}</Text>
    }
}
```